# How did the Wampa freeze Luke's feet into the ceiling of the cave?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars: Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*, Luke's attacked by a Wampa and knocked out.  When he awakens, he's dangling upside down, with his feet frozen into the ice on the ceiling.  How'd the Wampa manage this?  There's no indication that the Wampa is particularly intelligent, so how did an animal accomplish this feat of melting some of the ceiling, sticking Luke's feet in there, and letting it refreeze around his feet?

Comment: A Wizard did it :)

Comment: ^Fixd: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt

Comment: By licking his boots?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wampa)

> Wampas rarely killed their prey outright and never hunted when they were hungry. Because they preferred fresh meat, wampas instead always tried to stun their prey, keeping their victims unconscious, but alive, until ready to feed. After disabling their prey, wampas hauled the still-breathing victims back to their cave dwellings and, through different methods, secured them in the ice for later consumption. For some, wampas used their hot breath to melt the ice around a victim's legs and then coated parts of the body in saliva, placing them against the ice ceiling of their caves so they would freeze in place. The saliva also served as an anesthetic in the victims, which helped to keep prey comatose until the wampa was ready to eat. Alternatively, for larger creatures, such as the tauntaun, wampas frequently impaled them through the ankles on overhanging icicles or stalactites to keep them immobile. At times, several fresh victims were stored in this manner.

Comment: That's what I just said!

Comment: @OghmaOsiris But I have citations!

Comment: You kids and your music.

Comment: And a typical Wampa pass a large amount of is life hands up in is cave, waiting for is food to freeze on the ceiling.

Comment: Well, it's not like a Wampa has a lot to do on Hoth on a Friday night anyway.

Comment: @DampeS8N then why not add your citations to OghmaOsiris' answer and *improve* it?

Comment: You should really provide cites from source material, not Wookiepedia, if possible

Comment: @Pureferret I'll get right on that. Expect an edit in 2017.

Comment: @DampeS8N 2018 is here and still no edit.

Comment: @Abless Yeah, you're right. I'm running a bit behind. Definitely by 2025. Definitely.

Answer (score 7):

I would assume that it would use its spit and slobber all over him, then stick it to the ceiling.

From what I remember, the thing produced a LOT of saliva.